# Background of folkelore necessary to understand some questions

Tags: discussion

I have seen many questions about "Jinns", *just as an example*, for what I'm asking.

There are many, many questions looking for personal advice, and some questions about Islam, that seam to suppose some knowledge of folklore, the (hidden) background of the question.

To counter false, but common, believes, you have to know about them.

Is there any source about it on the net?